# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field : No qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

**implementation of interface is carried out using abstract class instead of concrete class.**

**org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:** Error creating bean with name '**contactController**':

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '**emailService**': ***No qualifying bean of type [com.proto.backendservice.EmailService] found for dependency [com.proto.backendservice.EmailService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}***;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.proto.backendservice.EmailService] found for dependency [com.proto.backendservice.EmailService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}.

**ContactController**

```
package com.proto.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.proto.backendservice.EmailService;
import com.proto.domainFrontend.FeedBackPojo;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Controller
public class ContactController {
    
    private static final Logger LOG=LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactController.class);
    
    public static final String FEEDBACK_MODEL_KEY="feedback";
    private static final String CONTACT_US_VIEW_NAME="contact";
    
    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/contact",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String contactGet(ModelMap model){
        FeedBackPojo feedBackPojo=new FeedBackPojo();
        model.addAttribute(ContactController.FEEDBACK_MODEL_KEY, feedBackPojo);
        return ContactController.CONTACT_US_VIEW_NAME;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/contact",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String contactPost(@ModelAttribute(FEEDBACK_MODEL_KEY) FeedBackPojo feedback){
        LOG.debug("feedback pojo content:{}",feedback);
        emailService.sendFeedBackEmail(feedback);
        return ContactController.CONTACT_US_VIEW_NAME;
    }
}
```

**interface EmailService**

```
package com.proto.backendservice;

import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;

import com.proto.domainFrontend.FeedBackPojo;

public interface EmailService {
    
    public void sendFeedBackEmail(FeedBackPojo feedBackPojo);
    
    public void sendGenericEmailMessage(SimpleMailMessage message);
}
```

**abstract class AbstractEmailService**

```
package com.proto.backendservice;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.proto.domainFrontend.FeedBackPojo;

@Service
public abstract class AbstractEmailService implements EmailService{
    
    @Value("${default.to.address}")
    private String defaultToAddress;
    
    protected SimpleMailMessage prepareSimpleMailMessageFromFeedBackPojo(FeedBackPojo feedback){
        SimpleMailMessage message=new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(defaultToAddress);
        message.setFrom(feedback.getEmail());
        message.setSubject("[Protoweb:Feedback Received from"+feedback.getFirstName()+" "+feedback.getLastName()+"!");
        message.setText(feedback.getFeedBack());
        return message;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void sendFeedBackEmail(FeedBackPojo feedBackPojo){
        sendGenericEmailMessage(prepareSimpleMailMessageFromFeedBackPojo(feedBackPojo));
    }
}
```

**class MockMailService**

```
package com.proto.backendservice;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class MockMailService extends AbstractEmailService {
    
    private static final Logger LOG=LoggerFactory.getLogger(MockMailService.class);

    @Override
    public void sendGenericEmailMessage(SimpleMailMessage message) {
        LOG.debug("Simulating an email service....");
        LOG.info(message.toString());
        LOG.debug("Email Sent");
    }
    
    
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profile.active=dev

default.to.address=xxx@gmail.com
```

**application-prod.properties**

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=xxx@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=xxx    
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=flase
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
```

Comment: Are you sure `MockMailService` is on the classpath?

Comment: Is com.proto.backendservice package scanned by spring?

Comment: This is a multi module structure and i have included them in protowebapp-servlet.xml.

**<context:component-scan base-package="com.proto.controller" />**

**<context:component-scan base-package="com.proto.backendservice" />**

Comment: @Andreas am sure i have included them.

Comment: Use <context:component-scan base-package="com.proto" />  instead. Or if you multiple packages use comma separated packages <context:component-scan base-package="com.proto.controller, com.proto.backendservice" />

Comment: Complete Source code link.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fb0shs8z3ykyq0v/AAAvS_iJfQEDxpzZClbG5kiKa?dl=0

Comment: @IssamELATIF,tried and problem still exist.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `abstract` declaration?

Comment: @ManuelJordan,i will have to change the entire coding pattern.Is it obivious due to abstract class,i might be facing the problem.

Comment: I want to know if after of *just* removing the `abstract` declaration other error arises.

Comment: Could you update your post to show us how you are creating the app? I want to know how the `ApplicationContext` is created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126274/discussion-between-prash-and-manuel-jordan).